# Filepicker.io gives "does not register as an accepted file" error when extension is allowed

Tags: visio, filepicker.io, filepicker

I have a filepicker.io instance where I am using the pickAndStore function to allow users to upload various files, however while testing Microsoft Visio I found the files are being blocked / denied upload by a yellow error that states it does not register as an accepted file type (and lists out all the files it believes are allowed)?

In my logs of the arguments sent to the function, I can see the full array of file types I allow and the 4 variants of visio I added are clearly there:

The four I added:

```
".vss", ".vssx", ".vsd", ".vsdx"
```

Full array:

```
[".doc", ".dot", ".docx", ".docm", ".dotx", ".xls", ".xlt", ".xlsx", ".xltx", ".xlsm", ".xlsb", ".oft", ".msg", ".ppt", ".pptx", ".pptm", ".pps", ".ppsx", ".mpp", ".pub", ".pdf", ".html", ".mhtml", ".txt", ".rtf", ".csv", ".xml", ".css", ".zip", ".tar", ".rar", ".vss", ".vssx", ".vsd", ".vsdx", ".mp3", ".wav", ".swf", ".ics", ".srt", ".wmf", ".eps", ".ai", ".psd", ".gif", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".bmp", ".m4v", ".mp4", ".flv", ".f4v", ".mov", ".wmv", ".wm", ".webm", ".3gp", ".3gpp", ".m2p", ".rv", ".rm", ".avi", ".3gp2", ".mpg", ".mpeg", ".ts", ".vp6", ".h264", ".arf", ".wrf", ".m2ts"]
```

However When I use "My Computer" as a source and upload any one of the twenty odd .vsd files I have to use as tests, all of them trigger the error to appear and deny upload:

[The image i am seeing saying that .vsd does not register](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xFWN0.jpg)

I'm not sure what else I can do at this point to fix? I don't particularly want to have to use mimetype in this one instance as it suggests not to use this along side extension in the filepicker documentation.

Here is the link i used that provides various Visio files you can use to test. I would rather not use the files clients upload using our platform as I would need to ask permission and in case they are sensitive. I don't think there has been a single successful upload (of a visio file, others are fine) so I would be surprised if it was file specific.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/confirmation.aspx?id=24023

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

All extensions are converted back to mimetype therefor you can't mixed extension & mimetype.

It appears that ".vss", ".vssx", ".vsd", ".vsdx" are in the database.

Could you post some of the files you are testing so we can check them ourselves.

Regards,

Dylan

Comment: I have edited the original post to provide the link to the resources I have been using to test. Any help you can give would be great as this is a problem for one of our major clients currently.

Comment: Yes, we looked into this. We're not exactly sure what is happening here.

Can you try using the mimetypes instead of extensions.

Comment: Does that mean the issue is just happening on our implementation, or have you replicated the issue and are looking into fixes?

I guess we will need to swap our entire array of extensions to mimetypes as you cant combine the two?

Comment: See Iain's comment, does this make sense? He would have replied but he didn't have enough rep. :D

Answer (score 0):

Filepicker needs to include "application/vnd.ms-visio.viewer" in the mapping from those file extensions. It looks like that's what the browser is reporting the MIME type for those files to be.